# Set Recyclerview below Appbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I want to set an appbar in my activity_main. For some reason, I am not able to set it properly. It is being set below the recycler view.

Here is my activity_main

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation = "vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_heritage_sites"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my app_bar_main

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <include
             android:id="@+id/appbar"
             layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_heritage_sites"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Why was my implementation not working?

Comment: It was for the layouts, to put views vertical or horitzonzal you should use LinearLayout, or you can use RelativeLayout setting layout_below etc. In your case it's posible that LinearLayout doesn't work for the AppBarLayout and DrawerLayout. Accept the answer please, thanks!

Comment: Makes sense. I must have forgotten basic stuff. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinearLayout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation = "vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_heritage_sites"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I fixed the issue using Relativelayout.

Comment: To my mind, `LinearLayout` is more straightforward in this case, but I'm glad you fixed the issue anyway.

Comment: Then, I would have to remove `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`. I have other components to add. So, I need relative layout outside.